# how to retrieving a specific range of data from Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I retrieve a range of data such as 20 to 40 rows from Firestore?

i am tryin this

```
connect().collection("users").orderBy("email").startAt(20).limit(20)
                    .get()
                    .then((querySnapshot) => {
                      console.log(querySnapshot.docs.length);
                            }
                        }

                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `after` function looks for all docs lower in the applicable index. In your code example, it is looking for all email addresses greater than the number 20.

Unfortunately Firebase doesn't have an easy way to achieve your stated goal. However, you can retrieve the first 20 docs then use a pointer to the last doc as the starting point for your next query:

```
final firstTwenty = connect().collection("users")
    .orderBy("email")
    .limit(20)
    .get();

connect().collection("users")
    .orderBy("email")
    .startAfter(firstTwenty.docs[firstTwenty.docs.length - 1])
    .limit(20)
    .get()
    .then(...
```

Comment: Great answer David. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+pagination